# Religion in present-day Colombia before Spanish colonial influence

Tags: religion, precolumbian-era

I am trying to find out some details about the indigenous religions in present-day Colombia and Latin America before the Spanish introduced Catholicism.  I have tried searching, but the indigenous religions are only referred to vaguely as "Indigenous Religions" or "Amerindian Religions".  Does anyone know specifically which religions were most prevalent amongst the indigenous peoples in present-day Colombia and the details of their practises and beliefs?

Comment: Not really a subject that I know enough about, but I think that most of what is now Colombia was part of the Muisca Confederation before the Spanish Conquest. There is a Wikipedia page on [Muisca mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muisca_mythology), but I can't be sure how accurate it is.

Comment: I think the answers you are getting are correct; why do you think that indigenous religions were not practiced in that time and that area?    Is there a reason you believe that they had some other religion?

Comment: You mean non-Muiscian population?

Comment: Why downvoting? A normal question, not bad for a starter. +1.

Answer (score 6):

OK, as I said in my comment above, this isn't really a subject that I know enough about, but in the absence of any other answers I'll do my best ...

---

Most of what is now Colombia was part of the [Muisca Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muisca_Confederation) before the Spanish Conquest. What we know about the Muisca was recorded by Spanish chroniclers many of whom were writing perhaps a century or more after the Muisca had been conquered. As a result, there is some debate about how accurate our understanding is. At present there doesn't seem to be any clear consensus.

Interestingly, the Muisca Confederation is also [said to be the source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2jetDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT154&lpg=PT154&dq=%22Muisca%20Confederation%22&source=bl&ots=Ka8sGQrVFG&sig=UPGGucbB0adUHiiZ2_WSZuKpLO8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXp4fJwbLVAhWIPFAKHR7dBQs4ChDoAQhGMAc#v=onepage&q=%22Muisca%20Confederation%22&f=false) for the [El Dorado legend](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/archaeology-and-history/archaeology/el-dorado/).

---

The [Muisca religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muisca_religion) was polytheistic, and the various deities were worshiped at sacred sites such as [Lake Guatavita](http://www.uncovercolombia.com/en/item/guatavita-and-the-legend-of-el-dorado), the [Siecha Lakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siecha_Lakes) and [Lake Tota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Tota) (the largest lake in Colombia). The Wikipedia article lists the [main deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muisca_religion#Deities) and [sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muisca_religion#Sites).

We know that their rituals involved sacrificing to their gods. [Artefacts made from precious materials](http://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/themes/lost_kingdoms_of_south_america/muisca_and_tairona.aspx), such as gold, have been recovered from ritual deposits. We also know from the Spanish accounts that [human sacrifice was practised](https://www.jstor.org/stable/980080?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), albeit rarely, and that the victims were normally captives from other tribes (although the practice might have been virtually extinct by the time the Spanish arrived).

It is worth bearing in mind that much of what we know about Muisca religion was recorded by the Conquistador [Gonzalo Jiménez de Quesada](http://www.psupress.org/books/titles/978-0-271-02936-8.html). The Muisca themselves have left no records of their religious practises and beliefs

---

There is also a Wikipedia page on [Muisca mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muisca_mythology). I can't be sure how accurate it is, but it does include a number of links and references if you'd like to take your research further.